# Parse Server on Managed Azure Services with DocumentDB for a mobile GIS app

Tags: android, azure, azure-cosmosdb, parse-server

I am wondering if using a NoSQL database such as Azure's DocumentDB would be appropriate for an Android GIS app. To better explain my needs, here is a quick breakdown of my app:

  - Android app that uses the Google Maps Android API to allow users to
     view and submit blocked bike lane incidents in Philadelphia

  - Users will be able to submit incidents to a cloud database, as well
     as view incidents submitted by other users. Each incident includes
     info on location, date/time, as well as a photo that will be stored
     in the database

  - The app is part of a master's thesis project, and funding is limited.

Based on advice I received from Microsoft Azure support, I am considering using Parse Server on Managed Azure Services with DocumentDB. However, one of my thesis advisors has raised concerns that this solution might not be wise, because DocumentDB is a NoSQL database. He says that SQL databases with spatial data support are much more efficient and can perform more spatial queries.  I am wondering if someone might be able to address these concerns and whether or not a NoSQL database would support the needs of my app?  In order to have my thesis approved, I need to be able to justify my choice of technologies. To help better explain my app, here are a few potential use cases that the database will need to facilitate:

  - Upon opening app, automatically display all stored blocked bike lane
      incidents within the past 30 days as markers on the app's Google Map
      (please note that the app is limited to Philadelphia)

  - When the user selects a marker, the info window should display the
      incident's location, date/time and a photo

  - Allow the user to search for bike incidents within a given polygon or
      search radius

  - When a user submits a new incident to the database, they should also
      have the ability to Tweet a summary of the incident to
      #UnblockBikeLanes (which is a Twitter hashtag commonly used by cyclists in Philadelphia)

  - Display geotagged #UnblockBikeLanes Tweets (that weren't submitted
      using the app) in the app's map

  - Perform coordinate system transformations, if needed

Any advice about whether or not a NoSQL database like DocumentDB would be appropriate for my app's use cases would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't fit on StackOverflow, as it's very broad and opinion-soliciting. That said: Your thesis advisor simply made a blanket assertion that SQL > NoSQL for spatial data (just remember there are *many* variants of SQL databases, and *many* variants of NoSQL databases, even within the document database space). Each has its pros and cons, some have spatial support optimized, etc. You need to do some benchmarking to decide what's right for your specific data and needs. You can build any app with any database.

Comment: Also: Plenty of documentation around spatial support for those databases which have it (such as DocumentDB, which is the one you specifically called out). And keep in mind: DocumentDB is DB-as-a-Service, vs installing/maintaining a database in VM's. So that's also something to consider, when justifying your choice.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I apologize that my question doesn't fit on StackOverflow. This was my first post, and I was a bit unsure of what is considered appropriate. I was hoping that by listing a specific set of services (Parse Server on Azure Managed Services with DocumentDB) and specific intended use cases, my question wouldn't be too broad. So, I thank you for helping me learn more about what sorts of questions fit on SO.  Would you suggest that I simply delete the post?

Comment: Regarding your second comment, yes I have found such documentation about spatial support for DocumentDB, as well as documentation on Parse Server's spatial support through its use of GeoPoints and GeoQueries. However, after sharing this info with my advisor, he still reiterated that a SQL database would be more efficient and allow for more spatial queries. That is why I decided to solicit additional advice, so that I could provide him with suggestions from other experts to help justify my plan to use a NoSQL database.

Comment: If you're comfortable doing so ask him if he has references to benchmarks demonstrating what he says. If he doesn't you could run some tests of your own.

Answer (score 0):

DocumentDB is actually quite efficient regarding spatial data and spatial queries while being a NoSQL database service. DocumentDB supports GeoJSON, and behind the scene it generates spatial indexes for your JSON documents. Thus it would allow you to perform spatial queries efficiently by leveraging spatial indexes.

Here are two links about DocumentDB geospatial support:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-geospatial-support-in-azure-documentdb/
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-geospatial/

If you are curious, here is the paragraph describing how we index and query geospatial data behind the scene:

> In a nutshell, the geometry is projected from geodetic coordinates
>   onto a 2D plane then divided progressively into cells using a
>   quadtree. These cells are mapped to 1D based on the location of the
>   cell within a Hilbert space filling curve, which preserves locality of
>   points. Additionally when location data is indexed, it goes through a
>   process known as tessellation, i.e. all the cells that intersect a
>   location are identified and stored as keys in the DocumentDB index. At
>   query time, arguments like points and polygons are also tessellated to
>   extract the relevant cell ID ranges, then used to retrieve data from
>   the index.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure why it was voted down (I'm still learning about what's considered appropriate for SO questions and answers), but I found the info you provided to be helpful.